# Twig debug statements not appearing

Tags: 8, debugging, theming

Still new to Drupal, but I've read over the docs countless times and can't figure this out.  I'm not seeing Twig's debug comments. I am using a sub-theme of 'Bootstrap 3'. Running on local environment in Windows (XAMPP).

In /sites/default/services.yml

```
debug: true
auto_reload: true
cache: false
```

I've cleared the cache more times than I can count.  I've also tried, unsuccessfully, making various changes to settings.php as well, however since these changes aren't in the docs I'm guessing they *shouldn't* be required for enabling debug statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to `sites/default/services.yml`

and write in the proper indentation with spaces as below..

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug : true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

*remember to follow the same structure as above

If not working clear cache from back-office :
http://your-drupal.com/admin/config/development/performance

Comment: Removed the default documentation above the statements, but it revealed the indentation level was correct.  No debug statements still an issue.

Comment: go to sites and make a file development.services.yml and write the above code and c if it works @JonCarlyon

Comment: also, try the **Drupal render cache** part  [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374) i suppose its a caching issue.. @JonCarlyon

Comment: Adding settings.local.php to /sites/default/ did it for me.  Does this means there is likely an issue in settings.php?  Thanks for the help wouldn't have gotten this today without ya.

Comment: no no i have also worked on this part some time ago  there is no issue sometimes u have to flush the cache at beginning itself...and then write the settings ...always happy 2 help @JonCarlyon

Comment: For those still struggling, the sites/development.services.yml file fixed the issue for me, after trying everything else.  Would be useful if that could be incorporated into the answer.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer, when all it does is repeat the OP's the set up?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I installed a fresh version of Drupal 8.55 and Bootstrap Theme. Modifying the services.yml didnt work. So I made a search for the word debug and find this file:

core/core.servicies.yml. I Modify this part and it work's

twig.config:
    debug: true

Somehow that file is taking precedence after services.yml.

Hope this help someone, but it's not really the best answer because we are modifying the core of drupal here.

Comment: This works for me as well!!

Answer (score 4):

According to Drupal [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914), the advised method is to copy settings.local.php from sites/ to sites/default, then enable it by uncommenting this in your settings.php:

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

Then, add this to your settings.local.php:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
```

(You can also copy development.services.yml, if you want).

Add this to your development.services.yml:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

Then, run `drush cr`. After this, you should see your Twig debugging.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8.8, I needed to do this:

1. copy /sites/example.local.settings.php to /sites/default/local.settings.php to enable local development services (this file enable those services by default).
2. copy /sites/default/default.services.yml to /sites/default/services.yml and change twig debug settings i the twig.config: section (starting at line 39):
   debug: true
   auto_reload: true
   auto_reload: true
3. run rebuild.php (this rebuilds caches). drush cr should work too.

I got there after trying many variations of the above answers. Apparently adding the "parameters: twig.config:" (etc) to the development.services.yml file is no longer necessary, as those parameters are now set in /sites/default/services.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling it manually in your site instance.

In /sites/yoursite/services.yml:

```
twig.config:
  debug: true
```

Comment: should /yoursite/ be the name of my sub theme?

Comment: It's not theme specific, but site specific; so, /sites/default for most cases, or /sites/yoursite if you're doing multisite or otherwise being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multiste installation,

1. Copy **/sites/development.services.yml** to your subsite folder
2. Rename it to be **services.yml**
3. Open your settings.php and find the following line:

> $settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT .
>   '/sites/development.services.yml';

4. Under that line add:

> $settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/YOUR_SITE>/services.yml';

5. Save your settings.php
6. Rebuild your caches (drush cr) and now Drupal will be aware of your configuration changes in
   **services.yml** file

Answer (score 0):

If you copy default.services.yml in sites/default to services.yml, you will see the twig debug parameter is already in there, set to false.  I didn't see this, and added the parameters/twig/debug: true at the bottom of the file.  That didn't work, and no wonder.

The twig.config section in my services.yml starts at line 35, and the parameters you want are under that.  This, in 8.7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and confusion was with the sites/default/services.yml file. I was editing the default.services.yml file and did not have a services.yml file.